# How do I setup a reverse proxy for multiple web servers?

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, nginx, webserver

I am fairly new to this, I would like to create a reverse proxy for me to be able to host multiple servers. So to get started will I have to change the port 80 on the web servers virtual host or can I just leave that? like for example in the header of the virtual host it has would I have to change the 80? also I changed the web server to 80.80.80.80, 80.80.81.81, that is manual, do I change this to automatic if I use a reverse proxy? sorry for so many questions, but for the reverse proxy server, in the router settings, do I have that server ip port forwarded to port 80? last question as of now (sorry again if I have more in the future) if I already have a website that has an ssl certificate from cloudflare and I do the reverse proxy, would it affect it at all if the reverse proxy is done only on http? Thanks!

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nginx/ReverseProxy

Comment: hi, thanks! do you know if the ip should be replaced with the website address or the server ip?